# How to deploy Cakephp website on Aws EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, cakephp, amazon-ec2, web-hosting

I am a novice when it comes to deploying website. I have set up an EC2 instance and linked it to my domain. I proceeded to install Apache and I have obtained this result when I open my domain in browser. 
[implying I have done everything right until here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dYnA.png)

Where do I go from here? I don't have prior linux experience one of the reasons for my situation. I need to deploy the cakephp project I have created. 
I apologies for the rather broad question, it was only very recently that I learned to code.

Answer (score -1):

Cakephp has a detailed documentation on how to install and configure cakephp.

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html